# Renumbering ordered sequence in R and then use the mappings

Tags: r

```r
dt <- structure(list(X2 = c(-1, -1, 2, 2, 2, -5, 10, 16, 19, 10, -9, 
-9, 23, 28, -21), X3 = c(-5, -9, 10, 12, 16, -21, 19, 20, 23, 
24, -26, -27, 28, 29, -30)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L))
```

Let's say we have a dt like this

```
    X2  X3
1   -1  -5
2   -1  -9
3    2  10
4    2  12
5    2  16
6   -5 -21
7   10  19
8   16  20
9   19  23
10  10  24
11  -9 -26
12  -9 -27
13  23  28
14  28  29
15 -21 -30
```

At the second column, I want to renumber -5 to -1, -9 to -2, 10 to 3, 12 to 4, 16 to 5, -21 to -6, etc..., and let's say they are the mappings.

The rule is to renumber the numbers in the second column while retaining their signs, to make dt become this:

```
    X2  X3
1   -1  -1
2   -1  -2
3    2   3
4    2   4
5    2   5
6   -5  -6
7   10   7
8   16   8
9   19   9
10  10  10
11  -9 -11
12  -9 -12
13  23  13
14  28  14
15 -21 -15
```

After this, I want to renumber the first column according to the mappings in the previous step, if the mappings exist:

```
    X2  X3
1   -1  -1
2   -1  -2
3    2   3
4    2   4
5    2   5
6   -1  -6
7    3   7
8    5   8
9    7   9
10   3  10
11  -2 -11
12  -2 -12
13   9  13
14  13  14
15  -6 -15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step of creating a "lookup" can be done by multiplying `seq_along(dt$X3)` by `sign(dt$X3)`.

My understanding of the second step is that you want to find the indices of the original `X3` where each entry in `X2` is present. If there is no match, we keep `X2` unchanged, otherwise we replace the value of the lookup at the matched index.

Assuming I have interpreted this correctly, we can do

```r
lookup <- seq_along(dt$X3) * sign(dt$X3)
data.frame(X2 = ifelse(is.na(match(dt$X2, dt$X3)), 
                       dt$X2, lookup[match(dt$X2, dt$X3)]),
           X3 = lookup)

#>    X2  X3
#> 1  -1  -1
#> 2  -1  -2
#> 3   2   3
#> 4   2   4
#> 5   2   5
#> 6  -1  -6
#> 7   3   7
#> 8   5   8
#> 9   7   9
#> 10  3  10
#> 11 -2 -11
#> 12 -2 -12
#> 13  9  13
#> 14 13  14
#> 15 -6 -15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>